# Level 3 Communications Monitoring

Tags: networking, latency

Does [Level 3 Communications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_3_Communications) offer any type of map of current network status?

It seems our connection here is getting high latency through their network.

Also what is the experience asking them questions about if one of their appliances is malfunctioning or being overloaded because you are receiving bad latency in their network?

Answer (score 1):

Check out

http://internetpulse.net

and

http://internettrafficreport.com

Answer (score 1):

If traffic levels and latency are what you're after, you may also want to check out MRTG (or one of the commercial equivalents, like PRTG), as well as SmokePing.

Answer (score 0):

I had been using them at home for a while as my primary DNS servers, but about a month or so ago, I noticed everything slowing down quite a bit.  I chalked it up to a temporary thing, but it persisted for a few days after.  So, I switched to OpenDNS but I'm not crazy about all their options like URL auto-complete, etc.  I just want wicked fast DNS... no frills.

Comment: Setup a local DNS cache...

Answer (score 0):

Bad latency in their network? There is the [The Internet Traffic Report](http://www.internettrafficreport.com/) web site or you can call your local ISP to check that out.